# Selectors only work when webpage is opened in Internet Explorer

Tags: uipath

I created a login sequence and my selectors for the `input email`, `password`, `click login` and `element exists` are valid. But only when I have the Internet Explorer page open on the website I'm working with.

I did that sequence again, and I ran it, initially it worked but when I ran the hole project it broke again, I tried "repair" and "indicate", I tried to eliminate the title but nothing is working.

[image: This is the error I'm getting when I run the project]

[image: This is how my selector looks like]

Comment: Please show the whole sequence. Its not clear if you use an Attach Browser scope or something else. It seems that your selector is just invalid.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are using selector attribute:

```
"title=ACME System 1 - Dashboard"
```

Try using a wildcard: `title='ACME System 1*'`, so it can work when you leave the dashboard.

This worked for me when I took those UiPath Academy courses.

Answer (score 0):

In order to automate tasks within a browser with UiPath, the browser must be open. There is an activity called Open Browser that's included in the default activities for every project. You need to add this activity to the beginning of your sequence and pass in the appropriate parameters, (ie. URL, browser type) you can then pass the outputted browser variable to an attach browser sequence and execute your browser automation acivities within that.

[Browser activity sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoWAT.png)

In addition, the selector that you have shared does not look like a stable selector. There may be other 'H1' elements on the screen that will cause your automation to fail. I would use the UI explorer to help you build a better, more stable selector.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initially use IE to indicate screen elements and then changed the BrowserType property to use a different browser? Please share the sequence to suggest you a fix for your issue.
I would also suggest you to modify the selector to 'title='ACME System *'.

Answer (score 0):

In order for selector to work the application needs to be open and the desired element needs to be available. So when you close the browser the selector disappears.
You may consider swithching to 'Modern Design Experience' and use 'Use Application/Browser' scope to make this more intuitive, and it will also automatically open the browser for you if it is closed.